# Ruby Script using Octokit: Making API Calls

Tags: ruby, octokit

I am trying to create a script that gets a list of all repositories from GitHub. GitHub has a ruby gem called Octokit that I am trying to utilize, but I am a little lost.

The API has a reference [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories). It shows that I can get this response using a GET request. I am trying to figure out how to perform this using the Octokit Gem.

I may be completely off base with this question as I am new to Ruby, but I'd appreciate some steps showing how this can be completed. If I should not be using Octokit for this, a recommendation for creating HTTP Requests and Parsing the appropriate JSON response would be appreciated as well.

The Code I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'Octokit'

client = Octokit::Client.new \
  :login    => '',
  :password => ''

user = client.user
user.login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along with the code you already wrote, you can get all of the repositories for the user who's credentials you're using when authenticating the client with:

```
client.repositories
```

You can also get the public repositories of another user by passing their login as an argument:

```
client.repositories('username_here')
```

Comment: I am looking to get the entire list of repositories though. I don't want repositories for a specific user.

Comment: In that case you can use [Client#all_repositories](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/blob/master/lib/octokit/client/repositories.rb#L74-L87):

`client.all_repositories`

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm close to where I need to be I think. I used client.all_repositories to get a bunch of values, but when I print it, it looks like memory addresses. Do you know how I can see the text of the response? My end goal is to get the name & link to all repositories with more than X number of stars.